# Using MQTT with multiple subscribers

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using mosquitto (http://mosquitto.org/) as an MQTT broker and am looking for advice on load balancing subscribers (to the same topic). How is this achieved? Everything I've read about the protocol states that **all** subscribers to the **same topic** will be given a published message.

This seems inefficient, and so I'm looking for a way for a published message to be given to one of the connected subscribers in a round-robin approach that would ensure a load balanced state.

If this is not possible with MQTT, how does a subscriber avoid being overwhelmed with messages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically you design MQTT applications in a way that you don't have overwhelmed subscribers. You can achieve this by spreading load to different topics.

If you really can't do that, take a look at the *shared subscription* approach sophisticated MQTT brokers like [MessageSight](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCGGQ_1.2.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/Developing/sharedsubscriptionsinmqtt.html) and [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com/) have. This is exactly the feature you're looking for but is broker dependant and is not part of the official MQTT spec.

Answer (score 4):

MQTT is a Pub/Sub protocol, the basis is for a 1 to many distribution of messages not a 1 to 1 (of many) you describe. What you describe would be more like a Message Queuing system which is distinctly different from Pub/Sub.

Mosquitto as a pure implementation of this protocol does not support the delivery as you describe it. One solution is to us a local queue with in the subscriber which incoming messages are added to and then consumed by a thread pool.

I do believe that the IBM Message Sight appliance may offer the type of message delivery you are looking for as an extension to the protocol called [Shared Subscriptions](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/238944/mqtt-shared-subsription-in-streams.html), but with this enabled it is deviating from the pure MQTT spec.

Comment: Shared subscriptions will also be part of the MQTT v5 spec

Answer (score 4):

MQTT v5 has the support of shared subscriptions and mosquitto version 1.6 added support of MQTT v5.

Check [release notes](https://mosquitto.org/blog/2019/04/version-1-6-released/)

Good article on shared subscriptions [here](https://flespi.com/blog/shared-subscriptions-yet-another-flespi-mqtt-broker-feature)